# Xamarin Forms CarouselView Image Binding Error

Tags: image, xamarin, carousel

I am using the Carousel View to display a frame that includes both images and text. I am retrieving the data from an API, the text binds properly to the labels, but the byte array does not properly bind as the image source. I have tried setting the source of an image external to the carousel view called "bell_img" and it shows the image from the byte array properly. I have also tried binding the image source inside the carousel view to an image that I have stored as a resource in my application, this image is showed properly inside the carousel view. Its very strange that the byte array image does not work only inside the carousel view, because both the things I have tried show that

ImageSource imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(event_list[i].image)); (works correctly)

And that the binding is also correct because it works with images in my resource folder.

[CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hC3xa.png)

When setting ImageSource2 as the binding, instead o ImageSource, the image shows correctly.

Comment: Welcome Gerardo. Rather than link to an image of your code, please copy and paste the code into your question (surround it with a code fence).

Comment: just bind your Image's Source property to the byte[]